# What is the typecast of an element created with componentsSeparatedByString?

Tags: xcode

I need to extract some info from a number of strings in infoArray. The layout for each element in infoArray looks like @"NO,YES,YES,YES,YES,NO,NO,YES", etc.

When I use the following:

```
[splitArray setArray:[[infoArray objectAtIndex: i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","]];
```

I can access whatever I need in the new splitArray with something like:

```
NSLog(@"Result = %@", [infoArray objectAtIndex: 0]);
```

and in this case it will print out correctly. The problem is when I need to use it next for conditions:

```
if([infoArray objectAtIndex: 0] == @"YES"){
    //do something
}
```

The above code obviously doesn't work even if the value was "YES".  I believe the typecast is wrong.  I'm a bit of a newbie.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should modify your question with the additional data instead of answering your own question.

To answer your question, use:

```
[[splitArray objectAtIndex: 0] isEqualToString:@"YES"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry about that I made an error in my notes:

```
NSLog(@"Result = %@", [infoArray objectAtIndex: 0]);
```

should be

```
NSLog(@"Result = %@", [splitArray objectAtIndex: 0]);
```

and

```
if([infoArray objectAtIndex: 0] == @"YES"){
```

should be

```
if([splitArray objectAtIndex: 0] == @"YES"){
```